# ANSI C and sqlite3_get_table: How to pass results array back to calling function?

Tags: c, arrays, sqlite

I'm trying to pass the results array generated by `sqlite3_get_table` contained
in a function called by another function.  Everything is working fine except I
can't get the array back into the `main` function. What exactly do I replace the
`char **sql_results` with? Here's the code:

```
int main()
{
    char **sql_results = 0; // help here

    sql_select_table("GetAirports", query_string, AIRPORTS_DATABASE,
             sql_results, &RecordCount,
             &ColumnCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
        printf("%s\n", sql_results[i]); // Generates "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

}

void sql_select_table(const char *query_name, const char *sql_query,
              const char *sql_database,
              char **sql_results, int *RecordCount,
              int *ColumnCount)
{
    sqlite3_get_table(open_database, sql_query,
                 &sql_results, RecordCount,
                 ColumnCount, &error_msg);

}
```

Comment: Sorry Monkey, there's no way to get bold formatting inside a code block. I removed it all to try to get something easier to read, I hope the lack of bold doesn't make the question harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to take the address of one of the `sql_select_table` arguments and that doesn't do what you think it does; `&sql_results` is just the address of a local variable, it won't let you modify the `sql_results` in `main()`.

Instead, pass a `char***` into `sql_select_table` like this:

```
/* Note that sql_results is now a char*** */
void sql_select_table(const char *query_name, const char *sql_query,
              const char *sql_database,
              char ***sql_results, int *RecordCount,
              int *ColumnCount)
{
    sqlite3_get_table(open_database, sql_query,
                 sql_results, RecordCount,
                 ColumnCount, &error_msg);

}

int main()
{
    char **sql_results = 0;

    /* Note the & on sql_results */
    sql_select_table("GetAirports", query_string, AIRPORTS_DATABASE,
             &sql_results, &RecordCount,
             &ColumnCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
        printf("%s\n", sql_results[i]); // Generates "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

}
```

Also, [`sqlite3_get_table`](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_free_table) is deprecated:

> This is a legacy interface that is preserved for backwards compatibility. Use of this interface is not recommended.

So you might want to start using [`sqlite3_exec`](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_exec) instead.

Comment: MU, that works! I spent hours trying to get this, so many thanks for the help.  I started with sqlite3_exec but found all the callback routines I was developing were just trying to accomplish what get_table already provides.  Maybe as I get better at his, I can drop the deprecated version, but for now it seems MUCH easier.